# Cognitive Services - Text Translator-API problems / Raindrops in dashboard

Tags: text, azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-translator

Text Translator-API of Cognitive Services doesn't work anymore and dashboard simply shows fog with raindrops in graphs with `NumberOfCallsMetricPart`,
`MICROSOFT_AZURE_PROJECTOXFORD`, `LatencyMetricPart`,
`MICROSOFT_AZURE_PROJECTOXFO` and so on.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Since it is your first question on SO, you might read [the guide on asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

If you see a **KeysPropertiesPart: MICROSOFT_AZURE_PROJECTOXFORD** error when trying to view your keys then it is because of an inactive Azure subscription as Microsoft Translator indicates in their answer.

If you see a **NumberOfCallsMetricPart: MICROSOFT_AZURE_PROJECTOXFORD** error when trying to view metrics it means that your subscription isn't registered with the microsoft.insights resource provider.  microsoft.insights is the Azure platform-wide diagnostics and monitoring service which you can read more about at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-overview-azure-monitor

To register this resource provider:

1. In the Azure Management portal click More services -> Subscriptions, or use the direct URL https://ms.portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Billing/SubscriptionsBlade.
2. Select the subscription you are interested in and then go to Resource Providers and click ‘Register’ for the “Microsoft.insights” resource provider

Comment: I was getting a `NumberOfCallsMetricPart: MICROSOFT_AZURE_PROJECTOXFORD` and indeed registering to _Microsoft.insights_ solved the problem.

Comment: It is very good answer, that you couldn't find at azure support.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can see the consumption in the portal only for a paid tier. S1 or better.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't help, because I don't want to see the consumption, I want to use the API but it doesn't work and even after creating a new resource of text translator, it shows the same fogs and isn't useable.

Comment: I used the translation service with many customers with their own clouds and they're experiencing the same problem - and it did work before.

Answer (score 0):

The rain cloud represents an inactive or suspended Azure subscription. It could be caused by credit card or payment issues. If you took advantage of the free Azure account trial for 30 days, it's possible the trial period has ended and you'll need to subscribe to Azure again in order to use an Azure service. If this is the case, you can read through the Azure Free Trial FAQ  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/free-account-faq.
You can also contact Azure subscription support if you need further assistance: https://buildazure.com/2016/09/01/fixing-azure-portal-errors